# jquery filter a ul/li using value from select/option

Tags: jquery

Ok this may have been answered but I can't seem to find the exact solution to this.  Jquery is still a little new to me and I suspect I am not selecting the element I need correctly.

I have a select/option and I want to change the items shown in a ul/li that correspond to the select/option.  The ul/li contains images that are displayed on the page and I am attempting to categorize/filter them.
I have another php function that creates the list of images and gathers all their filenames from a directory but as I don't want a page refresh, I am using jQuery, hopefully, to filter the li's and show only the images (with an appropriate matching tag in their filename, like the text="value" in this example but in the page weach actual filename has the tag) for the category selected.

I have a fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/mvprzy/RS6Ah/5/

I believe this should hide all the li's that contain an image with a 'src=' value (the image filename) that does not 'contain' the value of the category selected:

```
// hide those li's that don't match
$("#ul_svg").children.not(:contains(catvalue)).hide();
```

Perhaps a different approach would work?

Comment: so u only want to hide objects where the `src` attribute matches `catvalue`? that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/RS6Ah/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#catselect").change(function () {        
        var catvalue = this.value,
            ul = $('#ul_svg');
        ul.children('li').show();
        catvalue === 'all' || ul.children('li').filter(function() {
            return $(this).children('img')[0].src.indexOf(catvalue.slice(1)) === -1;
        }).hide();
    })
    .change();
});
```

Comment: Nice!  I realized that I forgot to include the _ in the img src category name - you would not have had to do that slice business making it even more difficult...
I had not seen the use of the || before, is that a shorthand or in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the record set down really well using the (drumroll please...) `.filter()` method.

```
$('#ul_svg').children().filter({
    var self = this,
        re = new RegExp(catvalue,'g');

    return re.test(self.src);
}).hide();
```

This uses regular expressions to find items in each objects `src` that will match `catvalue`, and filters the collection to only those objects before hiding.